# Pickle is saying it can't pickle a pygame.surface, but my object isn't a pygame.surface

Tags: python, pygame, pickle

Basically, I am trying to pickle a class called State, which holds the game state that I want to send over, which does not contain any pygame.surfaces. But pickling is saying I am trying to pickle one with this error: TypeError: cannot pickle 'pygame.Surface' object. This is my state class:

```
class State():
def __init__(self):
    self.choosen = [None,None,None,None,None,None,
                    None,None,None,None,None,None];
    self.Won = None;
    self.tile = [0,0,0,0,0,0,
                 0,0,0,0,0,0]
    self.level = 1;
    self.pnum = [0,0];
    self.pCards = [[],[]];
    self.ready = False;
    self.turn = False;
```

This contains no pygame.surface.
Other relevant code segments are listed here.

This is how the server sends information. I have socket declared above.

```
def threaded_client(conn,player):
global pnum
conn.send(pickle.dumps(player));
reply = None;
while True:
    try:
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        state = pickle.loads(data);
        if not data:
            print("Disconnected");
            break;
        else:
            reply = state;
            print(pnum);
        state.ready = pnum == 2;

        conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply));
    except:
        break;
```

This is how my network class sends information.

```
def send(self,data):
    try:
        self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
        p = pickle.loads(self.client.recv(4096));
        return p
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e);
```

Thank you!

Edit: I found the problem, the choosen array were images. One of those things where once you ask the question, you scrutinize your code harder to find something fairly obviously.

Comment: Looks like you're sending your player object with `conn.send(pickle.dumps(player))`, and I'd guess your player object contains a pygame.surface. A [mcve] would help us assist you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have this line:

```
conn.send(pickle.dumps(player));
```

Although you do not show the definition of `player`, since this is a pygame thing I am going to assume it is a Sprite. If it is, then it will have a `self.image` attribute that is a Surface. That is likely the source of the complaint.

Comment: Oh sorry, if its unclear, player is just an int  (either 0 or 1) of if they player is player 1 or player 2.

Comment: In that case you're going to have to provide more info if anyone is going to be able to help. I presume that you are certain that it is the pickle of the `State` class because the traceback points at the specific line where is is pickiling that? that class has a number of attributes that are uninitialised in the code you show. They are None, 0 or empty. What do those end up being set to? Please update the question with any additional info , to improve the help that can be given.